# Iterate two dictionaries and create a new dictionary where keys are not matching

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to merge the contents of the following two dictionaries

```
>>> key_dict 
{    
     '1': 'seq', 
     '0': 'seq',
     '2': 'seq'
}
>>> value_dict
{    
     'tedious; repetitive and boring': 'text',
     'worldly': 'text', 
     'ordinary': 'text'
}
```

Such that in the final list I have something like

```
>>>final_list 
[
    {
        'seq': 0,
        'text': 'worldly'
    }, 
    {
        'seq': 1, 
        'text': 'tedious; repetitive and boring'
    },
    {
        'seq': 2, 
        'text': 'ordinary'
    }
]
```

**EDIT:** 
Apologies, I tried this

```
>>> final_list = []
>>> temp_dict = {}
>>> for (key1, value1), (key2, value2) in zip(key_dict.items(), value_dict.items()):
...   temp_dict[value1] = key1
...   temp_dict[value2] = key2
...   final_list.append[temp_dict]
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
>>>
```

Any help on where am I going wrong

**Edit 2**:

After correcting, `final_list.append[temp_dict]` to `final_list.append(temp_dict)`

I get this

```
>>> pprint(final_list)
[{'seq': '1', 'text': 'ordinary'},
 {'seq': '1', 'text': 'ordinary'},
 {'seq': '1', 'text': 'ordinary'}]
>>>
```

Can somebody explain why the values are getting repeated, I am not able to comprehend that.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question and added what I tried so far

Comment: To be able to that all your dicts have to be a `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Should I pass the values to the `dict`s as tuples?

Comment: To resolve your immediate error  `final_list.append[temp_dict]` should be `final_list.append(temp_dict)`

Comment: @PaulRooney Dang. I added the output in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the order as specified in the question

```
from collections import  OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint

key_dict = {    
     '1': 'seq', 
     '0': 'seq',
     '2': 'seq'
}
value_dict = {    
     'tedious; repetitive and boring': 'text',
     'worldly': 'text', 
     'ordinary': 'text'
}

kds = OrderedDict(sorted(kv for kv in key_dict.items()))
vds = OrderedDict(sorted((kv for kv in value_dict.items()), reverse=True))

d = [{v1: int(k1), v2: k2} for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(kds.items(), vds.items())]

pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
[{'seq': 0, 'text': 'worldly'},
 {'seq': 1, 'text': 'tedious; repetitive and boring'},
 {'seq': 2, 'text': 'ordinary'}]
```

The issue with your original code could have been resolved by moving `temp_dict` inside the loop.
e.g.

```
final_list = []
for (key1, value1), (key2, value2) in zip(key_dict.items(), value_dict.items()):
    temp_dict = {}
    temp_dict[value1] = key1
    temp_dict[value2] = key2
    final_list.append(temp_dict)
```

Comment: Great answer :). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are actually on the right track. Values are repeating because you don't empty `temp_dict` at the end of each iteration. In fact, you don't even need `temp_dict` at all, just do:

```
>>> for (key1, value1), (key2, value2) in zip(key_dict.items(), value_dict.items()):
...     final_list.append({value1: int(key1), value2: key2})

[{'seq': 1, 'text': 'ordinary'},
 {'seq': 0, 'text': 'tedious; repetitive and boring'},
 {'seq': 2, 'text': 'worldly'}]
```

If order matters, then you should use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of normal a dict.